# Bundle-Seed-Error when trying to deploy a Sencha App on iOS

Tags: ios, deployment, sencha-touch, provisioning-profile

I am using sencha touch 2.3.1 and sencha cmd 4.0.1.45. Trying to deploy my sencha app as iOS native app with this configure-script:

```
{
  "applicationName": "TestApp",
  "applicationId": "alfaAuthApp",
  "inputPath": "/path/to/my/app/",
  "outputPath": "/tmp/IOS_OUTPUT",
  "versionString": "0.0.1",
  "configuration": "Debug",
  "platform": "iOS",
  "deviceType": "iPhone",
  "certificatePath": "/path/to/my/Dev-Zertifikat.p12",
  "certificatePassword": "mypass",
  "orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
  ]
}
```

Created a appId with certificate and got the thing working for iPhone-Simulator (not with this config.json of course) . Created a provisioning profile and linked it to the app id and my iPhone still get an error when running:

```
sencha -d  app package run config_iphone.json
```

The error is:

```
Bundle Seed ID is missing from config file
Failed to package application

[ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 6
 at com.sencha.command.app.AppPackageCommands$BasePackageCommand.execute(AppPackageCommands.java:46)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
 at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:148)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah too obvious. I have to include my bundleId which are the first ten numbers of the appId but now i get another exception:

```
The application was successfully packaged
Failed to execute system command while signing application with error 256
Failed to package application

[ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 6
 at com.sencha.command.app.AppPackageCommands$BasePackageCommand.execute(AppPackageCommands.java:46)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
 at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:148)
```